# Sawtooth transaction processor not respond to the ping

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I created a transaction processor using javascript sawtooth-sdk. When i run it locally, it works successfully and it gives me this message when running locally (By locally means running the javascript file using node index.js).

`Connecting to Sawtooth validator at tcp://localhost:4004`

`Connected to tcp://localhost:4004`

`Registration of [myTP 1.0] succeeded`

Then i dockerized it and when i start the container, it doesn't connect. It only has

`Connecting to Sawtooth validator at tcp://localhost:4004`

message. When i check the Sawtooth docker logs, there were no logs

My docker base image is `FROM ubuntu:bionic` and i expose `EXPOSE 4004/tcp` like this. What might be the problem? I know its coming from validator and what i cant understand is that this work locally and doesn't work in the docker file.

Comment: It's the container deployment question. The address tcp://localhost:4004 for your container is the container itself. You need to connect to the service on another container, so put your Validator and TP in the same network. Your validator's container name is your URL. Something like tcp://container-validator:4004. Expose 4004 from your validator container.

Comment: @Arun  thank you so much for the reply. I changed my index.js file and now it looks like this -> `new TransactionProcessor("tcp://sawtooth-validator-default:4004")` and in the same location my docker file expose like this -> `EXPOSE 4004/tcp`.


 I'm using sawtooth-validator-default validator from sawtooth docker composer. So do i need to change the defauld sawtooth validator ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the application container and docker-compose containers are residing in 2 different networks.

Find your network (probably this will be the name of the project directory)

`docker network ls`

Then connect the application container to the same network used by the compose

`docker network connect <network> <app container>`

If you need to do this in the start up of the app container,

`docker run -itd --network=<network name> <app image>`

Then, form the application, you can call the validator container name and connect,

`tcp://sawtooth-validator-default:4004`